# Flag changed item and list unread/unchecked items

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

Does Sharepoint have these 2 features:

1- Listing of the unread/unseen(like the email inbox style you can check the read/check items) Items (mostly files upload .txt) for a specified user.

2- Flag the item if changed: Flag the file name in the list with a star if it has been changed.

Comment: #1: I don't think you can do it by user, but you can create a column and insert javascript to capture who and when viewed each item in a list. If this is something you can use, I can give you this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to question 2:

1. Go to the list -> List tab on the top ribbon -> Workflow settings -> Create a Workflow in SharePoint Designer.
2. Add a name to the workflow -> ok.
3. Change the settings to start only when an item is changed.
4. Add an action "Update list item" -> Click on "this list"
5. Select "List: Current Item" -> Click Add
6. In the "Set this field:" select your title column; in the "To this value:" click on "..."
7. In the String Builder dialog window click "Add or Change Lookup"
8. Data source: current item; Field from source: your title column -> Ok
9. It will look like this: [%Current Item:Title%]
10. Add space and *
11. Click Ok -> Publish the workflow
12. Done! :)

Now when an item in this list get changed, "*" will be appended to the end of the Title column (or other column you specify).